# Using initializer lists through inheritance

Tags: c++

Is there a way to use initializer lists to initialize Bar?

```
struct Foo {
    int i[2];
};

struct Bar : Foo {};

Foo f{0, 1}; // OK
Bar b{0, 1}; // error: no matching function for call to 
             //   ‘Bar::Bar(< brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
```

Comment: Where have you declared your [Constructors and member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)? See also [Member initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `Foo` and `Bar` are both aggregates, so aggregate initialisation should apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Foo` is an aggregate, and aggregates can be initialised using braced-enclosed lists performing aggregate initialisation. That is why `Foo` can be initialised using `{0, 1}` even without a constructor.

However, whether `Bar` is also an aggregate depends on the version of C++ which you're using. In C++14 and earlier, aggregates cannot have base classes, so `Bar` is not an aggregate. It therefore cannot be initialised using aggregate initialisation and would need an appropriate constructor. [[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/304df23fde9da0cb)

In C++17, the definition of "aggregate" was broadened to also include classes with non-virtual public base classes, so in C++17, `Bar` *is* an aggregate and indeed, *can* be initialised using aggregate initialisation: [[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1722467040b90d6c)

Answer (score 2):

Since `Foo` is an aggregate type it's being initialized through [`aggregate initialization`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), which does not support base classes initialization as of c++14. But the good news are that it will be supported in c++17 :)

Example taken from cppreference:

```
// aggregate
struct base1 { int b1, b2 = 42; };
// non-aggregate
struct base2 {
  base2() : b3(42) {}
  int b3;
};
// aggregate in C++17
struct derived : base1, base2 { int d; };
derived d1{ {1, 2}, { }, 4}; // d1.b1 = 1, d1.b2 = 2,  d1.b3 = 42, d1.d = 4
derived d2{ {    }, { }, 4}; // d2.b1 = 0, d2.b2 = 42, d2.b3 = 42, d2.d = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

It compiles, but with C++17 where aggregates can have base classes. This allows for list initialization of base data members. see here for more:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

> The effects of aggregate initialization are:
>
> ***Each direct public base, (since C++17) array element***, or non-static class member, in order of array subscript/appearance in the
>   class definition, is copy-initialized from the corresponding clause of
>   the initializer list.